# Desktop monitor display flickering issue

Tags: memory, display, motherboard, vga, display-driver

Found my monitor display flickers while use, sometimes it crashes! I tried many online solutions including checking/replacing the VGA cable, tried with another monitor, but still the flickering persists. In some online forums I found a hint that it might be a problem with the HDD, but it wasn't, tried with another HDD, but still the same. I actually use Linux mint 18 cinnamon, tried with another HDD with Windows 8.1pro, but the flickering remains healthy in both OSs. I can't even hard reboot the system using restart button, getting a black screen on hard reboot. Always hard shutdown the system when the issue occurs. Is this problem occurs by any fault with the Motherboard? Or RAM sticks?

[image: Picture of the problem.]

```
Operating System : Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon, 
HDD : Toshiba 500gb, 
Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E7500  @ 2.93GHz, 
Motherboard : Zebronics G31 Socket 775, 
RAM : 2 x 2gb Kingston DDR2, 
Monitor : Samsung SyncMaster 733NW
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using graphics unit integrated in your motherboard (part of [Intel Q33](https://ark.intel.com/products/31917/Intel-82Q33-Graphics-and-Memory-Controller) chipset) as you didn't specify it. In this case yes It's motherboard that's at fault and your only solutions would be to get graphics card or replace motherboard.

If you have external graphics card try to switch to onboard graphics unit and see if issue persists.

In case you want to buy graphics card here's a link to tutorial how to install one "[Installing a Video Card](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyDxrTHDjXQ)".

Comment: Yes. Integrated graphics unit of Intel 82G33/G31. Any other solution ?

Comment: There's 1% chance that resetting BIOS settings would do something but I'm 99% sure that's a hardware failure. So fixing that means you need new hardware and in this case I HIGHLY recommend buying used graphics card(you can easily find one for 10$). Added a link how to install graphics card.